# Frequency analysis of very short signal in GNU Octave

Tags: signal-processing, fft, octave, wavelet

I have some very short signals from oscilloscope (50k-200k samples) registered over about 2ms time length. Those are acoustic signals with registered signal of a spark of ESD (electrostatic discharge).
I'd like to get some frequency data of that signal, in near-acoustic frequency range (up to about 30kHz) with as high time resolution as possible.

I have tried ploting a spectrogram (specgram in Octave) to view the signal, but the output is not really usefull. Using `specgram( x, N, fs );`, where `x` is my signal of `fs` sampling rate, I receive plot starting at very high frequencies of about 500MHz for low values of N and I get better frequency resolution for big N values (like 2^12-13) but the window is too wide and I receive only 2 spectrum values over whole signal length.

I understand that it may be the limitation of Fourier transform which is probably used by the specgram function (actually, I don't know much about signal analysis).

Is there any other way to get some frequency (as a function of time) information of that kind of signal? I've read something about wavelets, but when I tried using `dwt` function of signal package, I received this error:

```
error: 'wfilters' undefined near line 51 column 14
error: called from
    dwt at line 51 column 12
```

Even if this would work, I am not so sure if I'd know how to actually use the output of those wavelet functions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get audio frequency information from such a high sample rate, you will need obtain a sample vector long enough to contain at least a few whole cycles at audio frequencies, e.g. many 10's of milliseconds of contiguous samples, which may or may not be more than your scope can gather.  To reasonably process this amount of data, you might low pass filter the sample data to just contain audio frequencies, and then resample it to a lower sample rate, but above twice that filter cut-off frequency.  Then you will end up with a much shorter sample vector to feed an FFT for your audio spectrum analysis.

Comment: seems like filtering might be the best option, even if I won't be able to get spectrum as a function of time for such a short signal (2÷4ms max, with actual spark signal about 1 ms long), maybe I will be able to filter out all lower frequencies (to me those are just a noise), which on the scope look more like near-constant value and do something with that filtered signal. P.S. there are no cycles here ;) in ideal situation ESD creates N-wave, which would correspond to 1 cycle of sine wave (just a different shape), in real there is that 1 cycle and 4-5 very small (amplitude) "repetitions" after